# How to add husky and commitlint to angular project

Tags: angular, husky, git-husky, commitlint

I'd like to use [huksy](https://typicode.github.io/husky/) and [commitlint](https://github.com/conventional-changelog/commitlint) to my angular project.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

### [Install Husky](https://typicode.github.io/husky/get-started.html)

1. Run `npm i husky --save-dev`
2. Run `npx husky init`

> The `init` command simplifies setting up husky in a project. It creates a `pre-commit` script in `.husky/` and updates the `prepare` script in `package.json`. Modifications can be made later to suit your workflow. [Husky doc](https://typicode.github.io/husky/get-started.html#husky-init-recommended)

### [Install commitlint](https://github.com/conventional-changelog/commitlint)

3. Run `npm i @commitlint/cli @commitlint/config-conventional --save-dev`
4. Create a `commitlint.config.js` file at the root of the project.

```js
module.exports = {
  extends: ['@commitlint/config-conventional'],
};
```

5. in the `.husky` folder, add `commit-msg` file

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env sh
. "$(dirname -- "$0")/_/husky.sh"

npx --no-install commitlint --edit "$1"
```

6. *(optional)* remove the `pre-commit` file if you do not have any `test`

### Test it

7. Just commit something, ex: `git commit -m "Keep calm and commit"`